# On finite non-dense but co-dense subset of hyperconnected topological space

Tags: general-topology, dense-subspaces

Let $X$ an infinite hyperconnected topological space and let $F$ a finite subset of $X$ such that $F$ is not dense and with empty interior (or, equivalently, $X - F$ is dense).

Can we prove that $F = \emptyset$ or show a counterexample?

As an example, let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with standard topology and $F =$ { $0$ }. So, $F$ is not dense and $X - F$ is dense. So $F$ is not empty... but $\mathbb{R}$ is not hyperconnected.

If we equip $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite topology then we obtain an example of hyperconnected space, and in that case the previous example doesn't work because $F =$ { $0 $ } is dense (or, at least, it seems to me).
But also $F = ${ $0, 1$ } is not dense, and, in general, I think every finite $F$ that is non empty should be dense.

While I'm not able to find any example of an infinite hyperconnected space with a finite subset $F$ that is both non-dense and co-dense, this doesn't mean that it can't exist... and I wonder if, in this case, $F$ necessarily should be the empty set.

EDIT: There was an error in my second example. In that case, $F =$ { $0 $ } is not dense and $X - F$ is dense and so we have an example of a non-empty, non-dense, co-dense finite subset of an hyperconnected space.
Thanks to Eric Wofsey to point out my bad mistake

Comment: Why do you think $\{0\}$ is dense in the cofinite topology?

Comment: Because I was wrong :).

If I take $C$ = $\mathbb{R}$ \ { $0$ } then $C$ is cofinite (and so, is open) but $C \cap F = \emptyset$ and so F is not dense

Comment: Another example: Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the topology $\{X,\emptyset\}\cup\{(r,\infty):r\in\Bbb R\}.$. Let $F$ be any finite non-empty subset  of $X$.